# Scala Implementation of Multiline String

Tags: scala

How does Scala implement multiline strings?

```
  """
    | Blah 
    | Blah 
    | Blah 
  """.stripMargin
```

My goal is to implement my own parser but do it with 4 quotes rather than 3.

There are two parts to this, one is the `stripMargin` parsing, which is implemented in `trait StringLike` and secondly how Scala knows to interpret three quotes as a string (implicit function?).

Comment: While you can create your own string parsers like `s` and `f` via `implicit` class extension of `StringContext`, I believe that the multi-line syntax is baked into scala at a lower level. It might be possible via macros but i think even those are governed by existing string semantics.

Comment: I agree. `stripMargin` would be easy to implement, and for this type of things implicit conversions usually help, but I've no idea how to tell scala to  parse whitespace in the file as-is. My guess would also be something specific to the compiler, as you need to prevent him from parsing multiple lines.

Comment: It appears the triple quotes recognition is embedded within the Scala syntax parser.  For my purposes the implicit method call works just fine.  However, since the question is still valid, I will leave it for others' reference and my own learning (hopefully someone answers this in some detail regarding the Scala syntax parser - with code ref? please :)).